# Get the center of screen with Navigation Bar considerations

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, centering

I am trying to center a UIActivityIndicator and reuse it throughout my app.  I'm facing an issue where some of my views have to be under the navigation bar, and some aren't. This happens to give my activity indicator a lower than center presentation on views where the view is not under the navigation bar.  For instance:

[image]

All the answers on StackOverflow seem to fall under picture #2.

I've simply made an extension of UIView to show and hide the activity indicator by adding it as a subview overlay.  Checking multiple posts on StackOverflow, I didn't find anything that would duplicate this question.

My question is, in a production app, how would one successfully center this view for both of these situations utilizing only one function but still support IOS version back to 9.3

Comment: is your activity Indicator is centred to your custom view..if Yes ? then.. what happen if we show this indicator view on Window instead of UIviewController ?

Comment: Thank you @MAhipalSingh, your comment led to my answer below :)

Comment: ..great ..ah you save Bounty also :D.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SWIFT 3:**

Extension centers the subview in your App delegate's keyWindow...making it centered no matter where it is in your application:

```
extension UIView {

    public func addSubviewScreenCenter() {
        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            keyWindow.addSubview(self)
            self.center()
        }
    }

    public func removeFromWindowView() {
        if self.superview != nil {
            self.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A downside of this solution is that the view (activity indicator) is not automatically removed when the view controller presenting it gets replaced by, for example, navigating back or pushing a new view controller.

Comment: Yes that is why there is a remove function.

Answer (score 6):

you can get Hight of Screen + Top and Bottom

```
 var height: CGFloat {
        let heightTop = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height + (
            (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.intrinsicContentSize.height) ?? 0)
        let heightBottom  = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height ?? 0
        return  UIScreen.main.bounds.height + (heightTop+heightBottom)
    }
```

// then

```
indicator.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width/2.0, y: height/2.0 )
```

you can use `safeAreaLayoutGuide` it give you area of visible screen

```
   let indicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        let indicator =  UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
        indicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return indicator
    }()

        self.view.addSubview(indicator)


    let safeAreaGuide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        indicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: saveAreaGuide.centerXAnchor),
        indicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: saveAreaGuide.centerYAnchor)
        ])
```

Comment: I have to support versioning back to IOS 9.3, the safeAreaLayoutGuide was implemented in IOS 11, what do you suggest for earlier versions?

Comment: Works great, especially since window isn't avail in multi-window world.

Answer (score 3):

There are methods on `UIView` to convert points and frames between different view coordinate systems (supported on iOS 2.0+,  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622424-convert).

```
extension UIView {

    func centerInContainingWindow() {
        guard let window = self.window else { return }

        let windowCenter = CGPoint(x: window.frame.midX, y: window.frame.midY)
        self.center = self.superview.convert(windowCenter, from: nil)
    }

}
```

A `UIView` specifies its coordinates relative to its superview, so `centerInContainingWindow()` uses `UIView.convert(_:from:)` to obtain the center of the window in coordinates relative to its superview.

- Picture #1, view under navigation bar: the view fills the entire window, so the center point before and after converting will be the same.
- Picture #2, view not under navigation bar: the view fills only part of the window, so the window center after converting will be shifted to remain in the same place on screen.

Answer (score -1):

**You can use this:**

```
func setActivityIndicatorTo(view: UIView, indicator: UIActivityIndicatorView){

    indicator.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: indicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: indicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))    

}
```

> Or you can found center of screen below:

```
let w = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let h = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
activity.center = CGPoint(x: w / 2, y: h / 2)
```

Comment: This would give me the center of the view....but not the center of the screen, thank you though :)

Comment: @JoshuaHart: I have updated my answer, You need to get "UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds"

Comment: Updated Answer @ Joshua Hart

Comment: So using a normal iPhone screen size, let's say 375, 667.  Half the width is 187.5, half the height is 333.5.  

However if my view is not under the nav bar then I would have a UIView that is sized at 375, 603.  

Using the mainScreen center, my loading indicator will now be even lower, and still not centered.  You see what I mean?